# Mongoose display comments and stars(likes) for each post

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've been making an social web app . Users can make a post and other users can star(like) or comment on the post.

Each post contains an array of comments and stars ids. Each comment and star contain a reference to it's post.

My module structure  for post, comment and stars like this

Star Schema

```
const StarSchema =  mongoose.Schema({

created_at : {
    type : Date,
    require : true
},
user : {
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref  : 'User'
},
post : {
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref  : 'Post'
}});
```

Comment Schema

```
const CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({

post : {
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref  : 'Post'
},
user : {
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref  : 'User'
},

content : {
    type : String ,
    require : true
},
created_at : {
    type : Date,
    require : true
}});
```

Post Schema

```
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    content : {
        type : String,
        require : true
    },
    created_at : {
        type : Date,
        require : true
    },
    user : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : 'User'
    },
    word : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : 'Word'
    },
    comments : [{
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : 'Comment'
    }],
    stars : [{
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : 'Star'
    }]});
```

When i want to get a post with its comments and stars using this query

```
    Post.find({_id : postId}).populate('user').exec(callback);
```

it brings me the post but its comments and stars are empty even though it has comments and stars